# A skeleton for dealing with named arguments:

Tags: vbscript, cmd

Could someone give me a basic skeleton too that allows me to run diffrent command line parameters.

For Example

```
cscript TestSpeed.vbs /Internet
'or
cscript testSpeed.vbs /RW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

WScript.Quit Main()

Function Main()
  Main = 1

  Dim oWAN : Set oWAN = WScript.Arguments.Named
  Select Case True
    Case 1 <> oWAN.Count
      WScript.Echo "Usage: cscript TestSpeed.vbs /Internet OR /RW"
    Case oWAN.Exists("Internet")
      WScript.Echo "Test Internet speed"
      Main = 0
    Case oWAN.Exists("RW")
      WScript.Echo "test RW speed"
      Main = 0
  End Select
End Function
```